# DisplayPort without sound in lubuntu

Tags: nvidia, sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, displayport

I have installed Lubuntu on my old laptop with Nvidia graphics card. However, when I try connecting it to the TV through DisplayPort, I don't get any sound.

I have checked the Nvidia config and there is no place where I can set the sound to be outputted to the digital DisplayPort.

I also installed `pavucontrol` and tried reloading `alsa` several time. But still I don't get the digital output in the config tab of `pavucontrol`.

Besides, I realized that the built-in speaker of the laptop does not work at all (it has always been connected to the speakers and I have no idea when it stopped working in the last year).

I was wondering if there is a workaround to get the sound through DisplayPort (or is it because I am using a displayport to hdmi converter?)

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -c display,sound` and `pactl list cards`:

```
$ sudo lshw -c display,sound
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G94GLM [Quadro FX 2700M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f2000000-f3ffffff ioport:df00(size=128) memory:f6e00000-f6e7ffff
  *-usb
       description: Video
       product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2M
       vendor: CN0RPNX6724879CAAGRD
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 95.18
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=168mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f6ffc000-f6ffffff

$ pactl list cards
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 6
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xf6ffc000 irq 32"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "293e"
        device.product.name = "82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-dock-mic: Dock Microphone (priority: 7800, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

Comment: Could you add output of `sudo lshw -c display,sound` & `pactl list cards` to the question.

Comment: @Sneetsher Done, it seems that graphics and sound driver are all working, is that right?

Comment: Yes, drivers are binded. But pulseaudio does not list any profiles or ports  for digital audio. (DP). I have a dell e6410 with display port (nvidia graphic too, intel audio) i will check it.

Comment: I got another media controller for display port http://paste.ubuntu.com/18966556/ . Either you have an unclaimed controller or  that should handle both. Could you upload output of `sudo lshw` & `lspci` to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @Sneetsher I did that in http://paste.ubuntu.com/18976990/

Answer (score 1):

Go to system settings -> sound , you should see an option for HDMI/DisplayPort2 , select it and try changing modes until it works.

Use the Test sound button to generate noises.

Also check that the volume is actually turned up enough to hear it on the monitor, you might need to do this via its on screen display. It might possibly not have speakers of its own but have a headphone out that you can plug some into.

Comment: In Lubuntu, there is no system settings. I installed `pavucontrol`, but, there is no option for HDMO/DisplayPort2.

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve my problem in Ubuntu, have an upvote :)